# Foundation 4 - customize Orbit

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a problem with customization of Orbit from newest Foundation. From [the docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html):

*Orbit options can only be passed in during initialization at this time.*

```
{
  timer_speed: 10000,
  animation_speed: 500,
  bullets: true,
  stack_on_small: true,
  container_class: 'orbit-container',
  stack_on_small_class: 'orbit-stack-on-small',
  next_class: 'orbit-next',
  prev_class: 'orbit-prev',
  timer_container_class: 'orbit-timer',
  timer_paused_class: 'paused',
  timer_progress_class: 'orbit-progress',
  slides_container_class: 'orbit-slides-container',
  bullets_container_class: 'orbit-bullets',
  bullets_active_class: 'active',
  slide_number_class: 'orbit-slide-number',
  caption_class: 'orbit-caption',
  active_slide_class: 'active',
  orbit_transition_class: 'orbit-transitioning'
}
```

Mhm, great. But how to apply it? I tried

```
$('#slider').orbit({...});
---

$(document).foundation().orbit({...});
```

But nothing works. I know it's silly, but how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

"Starting in 4.0.7 you can also use the data-options attribute to pass configuration settings to Orbit."
source: [foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html)

Treat it like a style property:

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:2500; bullets:false;">
  ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {bullets:false});
```

Comment: Hi. It works well, but how can I use both `$(document).foundation()` (for everything) and `$(document).foundation('function',{}')` for settings?

Comment: I believe that when you call the foundation function, all other methods are loaded with default options, and only the ones specified are overwritten.

Comment: @toscho - You have to initialize options for Foundation plugins during page load, or else they cannot be overwritten.